# Pearson Correlation and P values for large data matrices python

Tags: python, scipy, cython, gnu, pearson

So here is the issue I am having. I have a bunch of large data matrices ~ 500 x 30000. I need to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient and if it has a significant p value. `scipy.stats.pearsonr` does not handle matrices so I wrote the following function to calculate the correlation and p value matrices:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
def corr_mat(X):
    N=X.shape[1]
    rho=np.empty((N,N), dtype=float)
    pval=np.empty((N,N), dtype=float)
    for i in range(N):
        v1=X[:,i]
        for j in range(i,N):
             v2=X[:,j]
             C,P=stats.pearsonr(v1,v2)
             rho[i,j]=C
             rho[j,i]=C
             pval[i,j]=P
             pval[j,i]=P
    return rho,pal
```

which works fine for small marries but takes forever for the large matrices I am doing calculations for. It also crashed my computer a couple times so there is that. I am wondering if there is anyway to do this better. I'm thinking I might have to do this in cython to speed up the looping but I am guessing I can non-longer use the built in stats package in scipy and might have to use the GNU library for C and I am not sure how easy this will be since my c programming is still pretty rudimentary (Mostly I do not know how I would handle large matrices in c) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can absolutely use `scipy.stats` from Cython. It may not be ultra-fast, but it will work. That said, it sounds like you're running into memory issues too, and Cython won't help with that.

Comment: You say your data matrices are ~ 500 x 3000, and in the code, `N=X.shape[1]`, so `N` is ~30000.  Both `rho` and `pval` have shape `(N, N)`, and each element of those arrays requires eight bytes.  Combined, `rho` and `pval` will require about 14 gigabytes of memory.  How much memory do you have in the computer where you are running this?

Comment: Not to mention that juggling around the `rho` and `pval` arrays elsewhere in the code might create more huge arrays. Innocent-looking things like `rho > 0.99`, for instance, even if used inside `np.where()`, as 0.9 GB is still something to be reckoned with.

Comment: You could save approximately half the memory by using the fact that `rho` and `pval` a symmetric (although you'd have to allocate them as a 1D array and calculate the indexing yourself)

Comment: I would just like to note, that correction for multiple comparisons will probably kill any (uncorrected) significant p-value that you may find.